# Microsoft Teams Client SDK does not run getContext callback

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams

I've tried to use the microsoft teams client SDK to get access to the current context of the tab. As of yet I haven't been able to get the getContext callback to run let alone return a context that I can use in any meaningful way.

I've tried to create a static html page that uses the client SDK by embedding the script and then log the context of the object. The SDK properly returns an object of the expected shape, but using initialize() then getContext() does nothing. I'm making this website as a tab inside of Microsoft teams creating a new tab and making it a website tab.

```html
<p>hello World!</p>
<script src="https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.4.2/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

console.log(microsoftTeams);
microsoftTeams.initialize();
microsoftTeams.getContext((context) => console.log(context));

</script>
```

This is the static page I'm using to try and get context logged out to the console.

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");

this.html;
fs.readFile("./src/index.html", (err, html) => {
    if (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    } else {
        this.html = html;
    }
})

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.write(this.html);
    res.end();
}).listen(7777);
```

This is my server I'm using to return the static html

I'm using ngrok to provide a tunnel from the web to my local server on port 7777. I can get the page to load just fine, but have yet to get the getContext() to run my callback function.

I expect to be able to get the context of the teams tab in the callback of the getContext() function, but that function never runs.

Comment: Could you please try the [Hello world sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-hello-world-nodejs/blob/master/src/tabs.js#L23) for Tabs and see if it is working for you?

Comment: I'm actually hoping to use the custom tab that lets you add a website by url instead of having to add an app to via the studio. I've already been able to get that to work.

Comment: Tab created using Website App doesn't get the Teams context, it needs to be a trusted URL. You can do it only by creating new App using App Studio.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT When you say App Studio, Do you mean powerapp ? I'm trying to get context inside MS teams client, using ng app hosted on trusted URL.

Comment: Please take a look at steps to create Teams App manifest using [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#use-app-studio-to-update-the-app-package).

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT, I'm trying to get context data in an angular app inside a tab of a team hosted using default website app provided by teams,

Comment: Tab created using default Website App doesn't get the Teams context, it needs to be a trusted URL. You need to [build custom Tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs) for to get context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Moving answer from Comments section:*

Tab created using default Website App doesn't get the Teams context, it needs to be a trusted URL. You need to [build custom Tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs) to [get context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context) for your Microsoft Teams tab.

Please take a look at steps to create Teams App manifest using [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#use-app-studio-to-update-the-app-package).

Comment: I have my ng app hosted in azure which as an https endpoint

Comment: Did you create Teams App manifest using [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#use-app-studio-to-update-the-app-package)?

Answer (score 0):

In the default application specified [Hello World with Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-gs-nodejs) if you put this script in the end of body tag.

```
console.log(microsoftTeams);
microsoftTeams.initialize();
microsoftTeams.getContext((context) => console.log(context));
```

Now you have to run this application in Teams environment only then this context method will get a value and not on regular html page.